# Jquery посчитать количество скрытых дочерних элементов у скрытого родителя

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="root">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Скрываю дочерние элементы `$('#child1').hide()`. Нужно определить, есть ли у родительского элемента видимые дочерние: `$('#root').child('div:hidden').length`. Это понятно, но вот если скрыть родительский `$('#root').hide()`, то и дочерние считаются скрытыми даже если их сделать `.show()`.

Есть ли другая возможность узнать количество скрытых-видимых элементов у родителя, кроме перебора в цикле и проверки `$('#child1').css('display')`?

Comment: А чем имеющийся способ неподходит?

Comment: Чем перебор свойств `css` не подходит? Люблю делать меньше кода там, где это возможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить количество видимых, в данном случае

```
$('#root > *:not([style])').length
```